# list of allowed drop down/select values

Tags: php, html

The issue is i am selecting option 1 and then going to the next page and i am coming back.The option MALE is being saved.When i try to echo it,nothing is showing up.

```
<tr>
 <td class="tdvisitbig">
  <select class="selectbig" name="gender">
   <?
   $arr = array("1"=>"MALE", "2"=>"FEMALE");
   foreach($arr as $p=>$v)
   {
    if($p != $gender)
    {
     echo "<option value='$p'>$v</option>";
    }
    else
    {
     echo "<option selected value='$p'>$v</option>";
    }
   }
   ?>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

The code which i am using to echo it is

```
 if($gender == '1'){echo "male";}
 if($gender == '2'){echo "female";}
```

Is there something i am missing .when i am selecting option 2 and save it and then try to echo it it prints out fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `$gender` being set to `$_POST['gender']`?  Is there perhaps an error in the initial assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
==
```

in the if condition..

Answer (score 1):

According to your echo code, it should echo `malefemale` every time because you're using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo, but i was using == and it still does not work